wireless channel setting in C programming Unix
I have an adapter that I set to monitor mode and I capture packets with wireshark, and send packets with sendto() of unix.
My custom sendto() packet doesn't show its channel, yet all other beacons/packets that I capture shows the channel.
Also, beacons with channel numbers don't show the corresponding byte with channel number info on wireshark. I would assume the channel number has to be on a frequency level, and not added to the frame as an information.
Also all beacons that I capture from my monitor mode device show the same channel always the same , like channel 1.
These the my custom packet without channel number,

and the 2nd picture is from a packet that I captured:

As you can see it shows the channel info as Channel: 1, coming to an example 802 11 beacon frame, here is an example picture below and this frame doesn't have any byte showing the channel number that seemed to be 1 in this case:

If so, how can I determine the channel number with recvfrom() on linux programatically?
All the beacons I captured from my monitor mode adaptor seems to be on channel 1, does that mean the monitor mode adaptor can listen to 1 channel only?
If so, how can I set the channel I want to send on as I use sendto() function on linux?
Extra:
If you want to see a sample of these functions on C, here they are:
recvfrom:
int sock_raw = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
recvfrom(sock_raw , buffer , 65536 , 0 , NULL, NULL); 

sendto:
int sock_raw = socket(PF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW, htons(ETH_P_ALL));
sendto(sock_raw, &pckt, sizeof(pcktlength), 0, (const struct sockaddr*)&ll, sizeof(struct sockaddr_ll));

So how can I set the channel to send/receive on on these in C ?

how can I determine the channel number with recvfrom() - you can't. "802.11 radio information" is taken from interface configuration, not from a packet. Your interface is tuned to channel 1, so it is displayed by wireshark.

You can find BSS channel from "Current Channel" tag in beacon frame.

I can see it in the tag, but not in the frame. Yet I understand. Then that'd be a question of another thread on how to set the channel on the interface.. @dimich

It's in "IEEE 802.11 Wireless Management" section, "Tagged parameters", "TAG: DS Parameter set: Current Channel". Normally you shouldn't capture beacon frames and parse them in an application. Initiate scan with SIOCSIWSCAN ioctl and read list of SSIDs and their channels with SIOCGIWSCAN. However proprietary drivers may have their own private API.

Channel/frequecy on interface can be set with SIOCSIWFREQ ioctl().

However modern interface to wireless devices is nl80211
